# Amazon EC2 PostFix can't send emails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta, centos-web-panel

i'm installed centos web panel on amazon ec2 the email send process worked in the first days and stop without any reason.
after search i can't know the reason is it because amazon blocked 25 post or my setup have proplem
my ip 15.188.176.162
my domain harvard-csc.us
          server.harvard-csc.us

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

Comment: i posted this request last day . until now no response from amazon

Comment: But what is your question here then?

Comment: Even though you’re using postfix and your own instance, and not SES, to open port 25, submit a support request to move SES out of the sandbox and port 25 will be opened for you.

Comment: what's expectede time amazon take to open the port

Comment: amazon refused my request to open mail ports. some one advised me that i must explain to amazon my procedures to protect my server from out going unwanted emails. how to write this statement